# MVC list of HTML helper attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SongName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "SongName" } }))
```

For Html helpers you can add attributes to them. However there isn't any intellisence that says all of the attributes you can add. I have tried searching online but I can't find a list of all types of attributes you can add here.

Can anyone tell me where I can find a full list of all attributes you can add in these helpers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no complete list.  This is why it's an anonymous object and not a defined class.

You can add any attribute you like to an HTML element.  There are a number of [defined attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes), but HTML itself doesn't require that you use only the defined ones.  Various JavaScript frameworks and tools may sometimes define their own, for example.  (And even in the list of defined attributes there is `data-*` which is open-ended and variable.)

Comment: Not to mention browser specific prefixes like ms- and moz-, that could potentially change with each browser version